# I cannot add number together and despite using parseFloat I still get NaN

Tags: javascript

I cannot add number together and despite using `parseFloat` I still get `NaN`.

This code;

```
        console.log(freshsnow_single_resort.fs_ski_resort_aa_advanced_length);
        console.log(freshsnow_single_resort.fs_ski_resort_aa_expert_length);
        console.log(freshsnow_single_resort.fs_ski_resort_aa_freeride_length);
        console.log(freshsnow_single_resort.fs_ski_resort_aa_extreme_length);
        
        let fs_ski_resort_aa_advanced_length    = parseFloat(freshsnow_single_resort.fs_ski_resort_aa_advanced_length) 
        let fs_ski_resort_aa_expert_length      = parseFloat(freshsnow_single_resort.fs_ski_resort_aa_expert_length)
        let fs_ski_resort_aa_freeride_length    = parseFloat(freshsnow_single_resort.fs_ski_resort_aa_freeride_length)
        let fs_ski_resort_aa_extreme_length     = parseFloat(freshsnow_single_resort.fs_ski_resort_aa_extreme_length);
        
        let expert_km = parseFloat(fs_ski_resort_aa_advanced_length + fs_ski_resort_aa_expert_length + fs_ski_resort_aa_freeride_length + fs_ski_resort_aa_extreme_length);
        
        console.log(typeof fs_ski_resort_aa_advanced_length );
        console.log(typeof fs_ski_resort_aa_expert_length );
        console.log(typeof fs_ski_resort_aa_freeride_length );
        console.log(typeof fs_ski_resort_aa_extreme_length );
        
        console.log( expert_km );
```

Produces the below in the console:

```
4901.39
2057.49
0
<<blank/novalue

Number
Number
Number
Number
NaN
```

I cannot understand what is going on... any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

parseFloat is not a function that will always return a valid number for you. The returned type is always a number, however typeof NaN is still a number.

```js
console.log(parseFloat("Invalid Number"));
console.log(typeof NaN);
console.log(typeof parseFloat("Invalid Number"));

console.log(NaN + 100);
```

You need an additional check and a fallback in case the result is NaN.
For instance if you want to treat them as zeros:

```js
const value = "<<blank/novalue";
const parsedValue = parseFloat(value);
const safeParsedValue = isNaN(parsedValue) ? 0 : parsedValue;

console.log(safeParsedValue);
```

You might also want a check for too large values, since when the number is outside the double-precision 64-bit IEEE 754-2019 the function will return Infinity.

```
parseFloat("1.7976931348623159e+308"); // Infinity
parseFloat("-1.7976931348623159e+308"); // -Infinity
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your very detailed reply.  I did not know this and now have a lot of code to rewrite.  Much appreciated @Krzysztof Krzeszewski

Answer (score -1):

first check for typeof and then convert to number

```
var value = "123";

if (typeof value === 'string') {
    console.log("It's a string");
    // You can convert it to a number if needed: var number = parseInt(value, 10);
} else if (typeof value === 'number') {
    console.log("It's a number");
} else {
    console.log("It's neither a string nor a number");
}
```